# how to refer particular node in firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

```
  FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Gamedata> options;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Data").child("Area"); <---Is this correct

 options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Gamedata>()
                .setQuery(myRef, Gamedata.class)
                .build();
```

[image]
I need to refer Area node, How to refer particular node in firebase. I'll share image you can see that and tell me what to do
Thank you.............

Comment: you're asking if it's correct, but you haven't said if it's working or not ?

Comment: database.child("Data").child("Area") try like this

Comment: It shows a blank activity

Comment: Nothing was there it didn't fetch that data

Comment: I didn't get any errors for that

Comment: What exactly do you want to display in your View?

Comment: I've created two textview for name and address. I want it from Area node how to refer that? see my code I'm just asking how to refer nodes